# Tab container hosting dynamic presenter widgets

Tags: gwt, tabs, gwt-platform

I want to show a tab container where each tab hosts a PresenterWidget.

Tabs are dynamic - they can be opened and closed. 
Moreover, the current selected tab should somehow be persistent in the 
URL so it can be shared or bookmarked.

I saw that GWTP has TabContainerPresenter, but it is for hosting a 
Presenter on each tab and not PresenterWidget. You also cannot add 
tabs dynamically, and the relation to place is (of course) static.

I also saw several discussions on this issue saying that if the tabs 
are hosting PresenterWidget, no special implementation is needed, so 
we can use any tab-container out there. For example GWT 
TabLayoutPanel.

But I don't understand how my PresenterWidget (that is hosted in a 
tab) life-cycle will be invoked on tab selection, or what should I do 
to have the life-cycle working (onReveal, onReset...)?

I guess I must build my own tab container that manages visible content 
through slots?

Any other ideas?

Ben

Answer (score 1):

Ben, the TabContainerPresenter is only applicable if each tab is a place. As for your problem you just need to set in each tab the same presenter widget. You might want that the presenter widget not to be a singleton if you are injecting them in multiple tabs. This is a sample of setting presenter widgets in slots in the main presenter:

```
@Override
protected void onBind() {
    super.onBind();
    setInSlot(TYPE_PermitContent, permitPresenter);
    setInSlot(TYPE_ErpMessageContent, orgErpMessagePresenter); 
    setInSlot(TYPE_ContractDetailContent, contractDetailPresenter);
}
```

Then on the view, on my sample permit and erp are tabs in the TabLayoutPanel:

```
@Override
    public void setInSlot(Object slot, Widget content) {
        if (content == null) return;

        if (slot == ContractPopupWithTabPresenter.TYPE_PermitContent) {
            permit.clear();
            permit.add(content);
        } else if (slot == ContractPopupWithTabPresenter.TYPE_ErpMessageContent) {
            erp.clear();
            erp.add(content);
        } else if (slot == ContractPopupWithTabPresenter.TYPE_ContractDetailContent) {
            contractDetail.clear();
            contractDetail.add(content);
        } else {
            super.setInSlot(slot, content);
        }
    }
```

Then add a beforeSelection handler on your TabLayoutPanel which may look something like this:

```
tabPanel.addBeforeSelectionHandler(new BeforeSelectionHandler<Integer>() {
        @Override
        public void onBeforeSelection(BeforeSelectionEvent<Integer> event) {
            //TODO: Set your presenter widget here with whatever argument it needs to populate itself
        }
    });
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! Can you show an example of the UiBinder you are using to host  the erp and permit presenters? If they are tabs, how come each one has different panel? They should be hosted on the same panel that shows the selected tab..

Answer (score 0):

If any selected tab should be persistent in the URL then it is a Place and therefore should be represented by a Presenter and not by a PresenterWidget.

Comment: You are right - but I have unknown number of instances of the same presenter - opened in several tabs. So it must be a PresenterWidget. As for the URL persistence - I thought to have the parent presenter (the one that holds the tab container and has a place) to implement perpareFromRequest(), check out some tabId parameters, and switch to the relevant tab.

So I still don't understand how to host PresenterWidget in some regular widget (as written in the TabContainerPresenter JavaDoc) like TabLayoutPanel and still have support of the presenter lifecycle..

Answer (score 0):

Here is the sample UiBinder implementation, this is of course static implementation, you need to make your own dynamic implementation if the number of tabs is determined at runtime.

```
<g:PopupPanel styleName="{style.popupPanel}" modal="true">
        <g:HTMLPanel>
            <g:HTMLPanel styleName="titleHeader" height="20px">
                <g:Label styleName="titleHeaderCaption" ui:field="titleLabel" />
                <g:Image styleName="titleImage" ui:field="titleCloseImage" url="{images.actionCancel.getURL}"/>
            </g:HTMLPanel>
            <g:CaptionPanel captionText="{lbl.contractDetails}" styleName="captionPanel_popup">
                <g:HTMLPanel ui:field="contractDetail"/>
            </g:CaptionPanel>
            <g:TabLayoutPanel ui:field="tabPanel" barUnit="PX" barHeight="30">
                <g:tab>
                    <g:header size="7"><b>Permit</b></g:header>
                    <g:HTMLPanel ui:field="permit"/>
                </g:tab>
                <g:tab>
                    <g:header size="7"><b>ERP</b></g:header>
                    <g:HTMLPanel ui:field="erp"/>
                </g:tab>
            </g:TabLayoutPanel>
            <g:HTMLPanel styleName="{style.separator}">
                <hr/>
            </g:HTMLPanel>
            <g:HTMLPanel styleName="buttons">
                <g:Button text="{lbl.cancel}" styleName="button" ui:field="btnCancel"/>
                <g:Button text="{lbl.submit}" styleName="button" ui:field="btnSubmit"/>
            </g:HTMLPanel>
        </g:HTMLPanel>
    </g:PopupPanel>
```